# Azure VM backup

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault

I have a windows azure VM. One standard data disc is attached to it. VM backup is configured in the recovery services vault. Is there any way to identify the existing backup containing both the OS disc and the other attached disc?

Answer (score 0):

Under Recovery Service Vault ->Backup Items-> Virtual Machines-> View Details-> Included disk(s)
[image]